# Bubble sort in javascript how to access property

Tags: javascript

Sort the following array of Persons in ascending order of ‘age’ using Bubble Sort.

```
var persons = [ 
  { 
    "name": "john", 
    "age": "23" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "harry", 
    "age": "21" 
  }, 
  { 
    "name": "jack", 
    "age": "25" 
  } 
];
```

Comment: You need to show some effort or people will be less likely to help you. This is meant as a help site not a free homework service.

Comment: [Property Accessors!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) use either dot `.` or bracket `[]` notation.  `persons[0].age === "23"`, `persons[1]['age'] === "21"`

Comment: My question how to sort age property in an array

Comment: while using bubblesort concept hw we sort age property of persons array

Comment: try this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort If you are still having trouble, let us know what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

We are not here to do your assignment for you while you are not putting in any effort. But try something like:

```
persons.sort(function (x, y) {
  return x.value - y.value;
});
```